# view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener leaks Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks

When I use the `GlobalLayoutListener` to see if the softKeyboard is opened or not the fragment is not garbageCollected anymore after it is destroyed.

What I do:

- I remove the Listener in the `onDestroy()` of my Fragment
- I set the Listener to `null` in `onDestroy()`
- I set the view that is observed to null in `onDestroy()`

Still leaks the fragment.

Does anyone had a similar issue and knows a fix for it??

My `onDestroy`:

```
   @Override
public void onDestroy(){
    Log.d(TAG , "onDestroy");

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16){
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(gLayoutListener);
    }else{
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(gLayoutListener);
    }

    view = null;
    gLayoutListener = null;



    super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show your `onDestroy` method?

Comment: @marcel, I posted a possible solution for you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe strongly removing the Listener, referenced by a View object, in `onDestroy`() is too late. This override method occurs after `onDestroyView`(), which supposed to "...clean up resources associated with its View."
You may use the same code in `onStop()` instead. Although I did not use this technique.

I can suggest this code, which I have used without any issues with the debugger.

```
// Code below is an example. Please change it to code that is more applicable to your app.
final View myView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.myView);
myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

        // Obtain layout data from view...
        int w = myView.getWidth();
        int h = myView.getHeight();
        // ...etc.

        // Once data has been obtained, this listener is no longer needed, so remove it...
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            myView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
        else {
            myView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

Notes:

- Since `getViewTreeObserver` is used for layouts, normally you need this listener for a short time only. Hence the listener is removed immediately.
- The second call to `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener`() should be crossed out by the Studio since it is not available before JELLY_BEAN.
- Pragma code `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` is not necessary if you're using Android Studio.
- Code `myView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.myView);` may need to change to a more applicable code to your app or situation.

Comment: This looks like a very clean solution and it succeeded in solving my memory leak.

I had to make a couple of tweaks/additions to the code (I have edited your answer accordingly). Can you just confirm, however, that I am correct in using `int w = myView.getWidth();` rather than `int w = viewTemp.getWidth();` ?

In fact, can you advise why you use `viewTemp` at all - i.e., why not just make `myView` final?

Comment: @ban-geoengineering, I agree that myView can be declared final in the posted example, changed it. However in my situation I could not change the declaration directly since I was using the override method getView().

Comment: @marcel12345689 You should select this as the correct answer (if it works for you, of course).

Comment: @ban-geoengineering, Glad to help out a fellow SO big contributor, and maybe another developer. It's only right you get help while helping others. Moving forward to the next (new) problem :)

Comment: Cheers for you help! :) By the way, reaching 1,000 SO points was one of the greatest moments of my life - even eclipsing the day I passed my road cycling proficiency test.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, but I resolved it by removing the listener in onDestroy().  Note the method to use changed around JellyBean.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
          mView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(mGlobalLayoutListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            mView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(mGlobalLayoutListener);
        } else {
            mView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(mGlobalLayoutListener);
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: when you analyze your heap dump, is the reference to your fragment still being kept in the tree observer's list of listeners?  If that's the case, maybe try keeping a reference to the object you initially get from getViewTreeObserver().  Maybe somehow its being changed between onCreate and onDestroy?

Comment: @ban-geoengineering did you make the call to the method before super.onDestroy()?  The tree observer can be changed by the destroy method i believe.

Comment: Yes, I'd tried that. I think the tree observer was no longer alive by the time onDestroy() was reached. The Original Android's answer has sorted things, but thanks for your help also.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe it's a bit overkill, but it's hard to tell anything for sure without sources, so try this. Make your `gLayoutListener` a static inner class (to not keep a strong reference to your fragment).

If you need to perform some operations with fragment or it's fields inside listener, create a `WeakReference<YourFragment>` inside the constructor of your custom listener class and access your fragment through this reference. Don't forget to do the check `weakref.get() != null`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this, you can try creating a Custom Layout and place this as your root view in your xml.

```
class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout{
      public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
             super(context, attrs);       
      } 

}
```

Then override the onsizechanged method

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    if (h < oldh) {
        // there is a difference, means keyboard is open.
    } else {

    }
}
```

I am under the assumption that your application supports only one mode (Portrait or Landscape)

**Update**:

Do everything in

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView(){
     super.onDestroyView();

}
```

Because I think you are initializing listener in `onCreateView()`, so listener should be removed in `onDestoryView()`. onDestroy() will be called only when the fragment is destroyed, not during state change.

Check the [Fragment life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem in a custom view. I registered a `onPreDrawListener` over a child view in the custom view constructor, and de-registered it in `onDetachedFromWindow`. The memory leak persisted. To solve it I tried everything, but in the end I had to write an alternative mechanism not based on TreeObserver.