# fragments leaking memory

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am currently developing an Android application using fragments and i am encountering a memory leak that forces my app to close after a while.

The main activity of the app features 3 fragments side by side using a viewpager which can be swiped between. The middle fragment features a catalog for our store.

When the user clicks a category in the catalog, a new fragment is loaded with more options; the brands in the category. The user can then click one of these brands to view the products within it. The user can then click a product and view it on the full screen with more details.

Each time the user clicks on of these buttons, a new fragment is created showing the content for which button they have clicked.

The fragments go like this:

```
Catalog -> Brands -> All Products -> Indiviudal Product
```

To change the fragment being shown, I am using this code:

```
Brands brandsFragment = new Brands();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.catalogcontent, brandsFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

When the user clicks on the back button, they are directed to the previous fragment. This is what i want to happen, however it seems to be creating an entirely new fragment instead of using the old one.

This is causing huge memory leaks when viewing some of our larger brands.

[image]

When the user presses the back button, the current fragment they are on should be destroyed but they seem to be persisting.

I have found an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20023140/9364403

However, the answer suggests using the .add() function, where as I am currently using the .replace() function. What is the difference in these?

I have also tried to clear the backstack completely but that does not seem to clear the memory.

the Android Profiler tool (shown in the image) shows that the most memory being used up is under Java. Is this actually something to do with the fragments or is there some other issue with my application?

Thanks.